# Adding hyperlink to a pdf being created via designmerge

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am working with InDesign hyperlink tags and am having an issue with the output. I have <HyperlinkDestUrl:http://www.adobe.com>Adobe in the InDesign document. What I want to do is output a PDF with just "Adobe" as a link to the hyperlink destination. Unfortunately, when I create the PDF, it is just typing out the <HyperlinkDestUrl:http://www.adobe.com>Adobe. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally typed `<HyperlinkDestUrl:http://www.adobe.com>` into a text frame in your document, nothing is going to happen.

You are supposed to select the word(s) you want to link ("Adobe" in your case) in your text frame, then use the Hyperlink panel to set the URL (http://www.adobe.com).

Also, when exporting the PDF, make sure the Hyperlinks checkbox is selected in the export options dialog.

See [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS2162F434-F475-4b73-950B-B23DA7744492.html) for more help.